# Default parameter in curried function

Tags: scala

In the following, I have a class `CurryDefaultDemo` with one parameter in the constructor, and the parameter has a default value which is a curried function.

```
scala> object Demo {                                             
     |                                                           
     |   type myF = String => Int                                 
     |                                                           
     |   def f(x: Int = 1)(y: String) = x + y.toInt                        
     |                                                           
     | }                                                         
defined module Demo

scala> import Demo._                                                  
import Demo._                                                         

scala> class CurryDefaultDemo(fun: myF = f())
defined class CurryDefaultDemo
```

If the default value `f()` is replaced by `f`, I get the following error:

```
scala> class CurryDefaultDemo(fun: myF = f)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String => Int
 required: Int
       class CurryDefaultDemo(fun: myF = f)
                                         ^
```

I know that `f` would be a partial function `String => Int`. 
Where does the "required: Int " come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f` is neither a `PartialFunction`, a partially-applied function, or even a function at all. `f` is a method. `f` has two parameter lists and requires both an `Int` and `String` to be invoked. If you convert `f` to a function ("eta-expand"), i.e. `f _` you get a curried function of type `Int => String => Int`.

Now, what is `f()`? Since there is only a single list of parentheses, only the first parameter list is applied, and since no parameters are supplied it uses the defaults, so `f()` is equivalent to `f(1)`. In the definition of `CurryDefaultDemo` Scala knows that this expression must be a `myF`, i.e. a `String => Int`, so it creates a function that is equivalant to `x => f(1)(x)`.

Why doesn't plain `f` work? Well, Scala sees you want a `myF`, which is a kind of function, so it tries to eta-expand `f`, gets a `Int => String => Int`, which is a function with return type `String => Int`, which doesn't match the return type of `Int` that a `myF` must have.